# SSO SAML in dot net web application using a Microsoft package

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0, okta

I would like to integrate SSO SAML2 in my asp.net web application.

I try with AspNetSaml package and it works good. But I'd like to use an official package from Microsoft.

Can anyone help me to reach my goal with an example please?

I find this package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml` created by Microsoft, but I don't find any sample for how to use it to integrate SSO in my application.
I use "Okta" as Identity provider".

Comment: What exactly your scenario? Is Okta controlled by your organization and you want to login into you app using saml or you want to allow other organizations to login into your app using saml?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "official" SAML 2.0 package from Microsoft.

There are a lot of other client-side [SAML stacks](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) you can use.